# ASP.NET DataGrid, DevExpress Grid or Report

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am new to asp.net and I want to create a table on my site.
The table should display data in a year-by-year manner (every row is another year).
When a row is clicked data in the table should change to the month-by-month data and so on.
I do not wnat to have another table under the first one or open new site.
i want to change columns and data binding in the table that is loaded as the first one.

I was wondering if it can be done using DataGrid or maybe I should think about some DevExpress
controls? I heard they are cool stuff :)

Oh, and one more thing - I want to generate report to pdf from data that is currently being shown.
Any suggestions how to do it? Like I said I am new in asp.net.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

surely you can use [DevExpress ASPxGridView](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/) or even the MVC Grid extensions, both have no code required pdf/excel/HTML export. as you said, cool stuff, we just bought 14 licenses of their DXperience subscription, planning to use mostly the MVC and SL controls.

Comment: I agree DevExpress ASPxGridView will do it, especially if you are considering exporting

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about DevExpress but I know what you are describing can be accomplished using a plain old ASP.NET GridView.  The DataGrid is actually a somewhat deprecated control, so you wouldn't typically use that with a newer ASP.NET application.